# jQuery UI tabs script convert my text with OL in tab panel in tab style

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm having some trouble with jQuery UI tabs. I'm using the default tab markup and i want to display a list in content of my tabs. Like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
    <ol>
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
    <ol>
        <li>Third</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use OL to create list in text. But my ol converted to tab style on a page:

```
<ol class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"></ol>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine in jsfidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xurff/

Which version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?